# .copy() makes reference to dict not copy Python

Tags: python, dictionary, copy

I have problem with dict's method - copy(),
I make copy of the "tab_bin" - "HERE 02" in the code and then I modifi it - "HERE 01".
And when at the end of code it prints "tab_bin", it prints modyfied version of "tab_bin".
Also I know my code is a litte messy and names of variables look weird because they are in polish.
My code:

```
def setting(akcje,n,m):
    def zmiana():
        Zm_1 = []
        Zm_2 = []
        for x in range(akcje[1], akcje[3]+1):
            Zm_1.append(x)
        for y in range(akcje[0], akcje[2]+1):
            Zm_2.append(y)
        return Zm_1, Zm_2
    def kreator_tab():
        if bool(tab_bin) == False:
            for x in range(1, n+1):
                for y in range(m):
                    tab_bin.setdefault(x, []).append(0)
        for key, value in tab_bin.items():
            for x in Zm_2:
                if key == x:
                    for y in Zm_1:
                        if value[y-1] == 0:  value[y-1] = 1
                        else:   value[y-1] = 0

    def operacje_proste(akcje, liczba_operacji):
        def kreator_zmian():
            ZmX = []
            ZmY = []
            for x in range(1, akcje[1]+1):
                ZmX.append(x)
            for y in range(1, akcje[0]+1):
                ZmY.append(y)
            return ZmX, ZmY
        def kreator_tab_prostych():
            for keys, values in tab_operacyjna.items(): # <- HERE 01
                for x in ZmY:
                    if keys == x:
                        for y in ZmX:
                            if values[y-1] == 0:  values[y-1] = 1
                            else:   values[y-1] = 0
            return liczba_operacji+1
        def d():
            suma =0
            for value in tab_operacyjna.values():
                for x in value:
                    suma+=x
            if suma == 0:   return  print(liczba_operacji)
            else:
                return operacje_proste([max(ZmY),max(ZmX)-1], liczba_operacji)
        ZmX,ZmY= kreator_zmian()
        liczba_operacji = kreator_tab_prostych()
        d()

    Zm_1, Zm_2 = zmiana()
    kreator_tab()
    tab_operacyjna = tab_bin.copy() # <- HERE 02
    operacje_proste([max(Zm_2),max(Zm_1)], 0)

def wrapper():  
    n = 2 
    m = 3 
    q = 3
    akcje = [1,2,2,2]
    setting(akcje,n,m)
    print(tab_bin)
wrapper()
```

[EDIT]:
Okey, to explain more clearly what I mean I will add `print()` to the code and show output.
Code:

```
     tab_operacyjna = tab_bin.copy()
     print(tab_bin, "- tab_bin ",tab_operacyjna,"- tab_operacyjna")
     operacje_proste([max(Zm_2),max(Zm_1)], 0)
     print(tab_bin, "- tab_bin ",tab_operacyjna,"- tab_operacyjna")
```

OutPut:
{1: [0, 1, 0], 2: [0, 1, 0]} - tab_bin {1: [0, 1, 0], 2: [0, 1, 0]} - tab_operacyjna

{1: [0, 0, 0], 2: [0, 0, 0]} - tab_bin {1: [0, 0, 0], 2: [0, 0, 0]} - tab_operacyjna

Even if in `operacje_proste()` I don't use `tab_bin` it changes just like `tab_operacyja` on which I make changes. I hope this edit will make it more clear.

Comment: you need to see the scope  of the variable defined, and where you are accessing them

Comment: No, `dict.copy()` absolutely makes a copy. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I mean it absolutely make copy, but I don't know what I did wrong that it modifies "tab_bin".

Comment: Don't post code int he comments, edit your quesiton to provide a [mcve]

Comment: But, I guess you think that `.copy` is a deep copy, it will be a shallow copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As juanpa.arrivillaga wrote I thought that `.copy` works like `.deepcopy()`. For anyone who has problem like this one just check [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html).